# Displaying tables in the title panel on R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need to display 2 tables side by Side in the titlePanel on R Shiny

Something LIke

```
titlePanel(
    #This is the heading
    "Animal Features",
    # Then I need to display a table, something like
#     "Animal",                  "Animal Type",                         
#     "Tiger",                  "Mammal"    ,                       
#     "Tuna",                   "Fish",                         
#     "Eagle",                  "Bird"          

#then next to it I need to display another table unconnected to the previous one, something like

#     "Eating Habits",        "Eats",                       
#     "Omnivore",             "Everything", ,                       
#     "Carnovore",            "Meat",                           
#     "Herbivore",             "Vegetables" 
)
```

However, everything I have tried so far makes it appear as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution?

```
titlePanel(HTML("<div style='float:right;'>Old Faithful Geyser Data</div>
                   <div style='font-size:12px; float:left;'><table><tr><td>bla</td><td>bla</td></tr><tr><td>bla</td><td>bla</td></tr></table></div>
                   <div><table><tr><td>bla1</td><td>bla2</td></tr><tr><td>bla3</td><td>bla4</td></tr></table></div>"))
```

Dirty hack but it seems to work.